# AWS chatbot Error errorMessage: "'currentIntent'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

[image]
After I deploy it, it will give me this error message(please see the picture attached)
I am wondering why it cannot recognized the currentIntent type in event. Does it belong to the event? Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with your call to API Gateway as seen on the 2nd line in the error trace:-

```
apigClientFactory is not defined
```

Check your import statements to ensure that you've imported the client SDK correctly and that you've instantiated the API Gateway client.